# Antialiasing in ILNumerics

Tags: graph, lines, antialiasing, ilnumerics, figures

In ILNumerics, how to use the anti-aliasing? I can't find how to use it in the tutorial. My graphs are like this:

[image]

I need smoother lines as this graphs (that we build with canvas in WPF):

[image]

**Update:**

I try the solution. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
var lineV = new ILLinePlot(ILMath.tosingle(verticals["1,0;:"]), lineWidth: 3, markerStyle: MarkerStyle.None); 
lineV.Line.Antialiasing = true;  

var pc = new ILPlotCube(); 
pc.Add(lineV);  

var sceneV = new ILScene(); 
sceneV.Add(pc);  

GradientVerticalilPanel.Scene = sceneV;      
GradientVerticalilPanel.Refresh();
```

But it didn't work. I mean, there is no changes visually. My lines are not going smoother, although there is no error.

Comment: You probably know: since you have rotated the plot cube and there is the Z axis left over – you can hide it by `plotCube.Axes.ZAxis.Visible = false`

Answer (score 0):

Make the lines thicker (at least 3px) and set `ILLinePlot.Line.Antialiasing = true`.

Edit: Antialiasing is supported by OpenGL drivers. The software renderer in ILNumerics (GDI driver) does not support antialiasing, since it would make the rendering even more slow.

Comment: It didn't work. Where is my mistakes? `var lineV = new ILLinePlot(ILMath.tosingle(verticals["1,0;:"]), lineWidth: 3, markerStyle: MarkerStyle.None);
lineV.Line.Antialiasing = true;

var pc = new ILPlotCube();
pc.Add(lineV);

var sceneV = new ILScene();
sceneV.Add(pc);

GradientVerticalilPanel.Scene = sceneV;
GradientVerticalilPanel.Refresh();`

Comment: what do you mean by "It didn't work"? Can you please update your question? Thanks